# gtksourceview compiling in code blocks

Tags: c++, gtk, codeblocks, gtksourceview

i want to use gtksourceview in my c++ project. I dig around the IDE of code::blocks and really find it helpfull. i specify gtkmm directory in linker and include options but as i look for gtksourceview i found a libgtksourceview-2.0-0.dll file i really don't know how to add this in code::blocks and use gtksourceview. I am have programming experience in C for microcontrollers just and now i have not really idea about the compilation process of gcc and g++. and can i able to add the file directives as

```
    #include <gtksourceview/gtksourceview.h>
```

please help 
sorry if it seems so basic question for someone but i really stuck of to compile the code and then asking. 
I am using windows by the way. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have the developement packages if gtksourceview installed? Have you set the additional include directories correctly (that you are able to find gtksourceview)

Comment: i think gtksourceview is based on gtk+2.x i can run gtk+ applications and have buit basic window application in gtk+ so and also xmllib available but i dont know how to install sourcview i have all dependencies available and have tested them.(mentioned in gtksourceview website)

Answer (score 1):

There are two different things: the runtime libraries and the development headers.  The former allows you to run the applications (also to link them), the later to compile them.  Either you are missing the header files (gtksourceview.h in your example) or setting the PATH in your IDE to find the header files.

Check the [manual](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en3.html#x3-350001.11.14) for 'Including libraries'.